# OOP Interfaces and Abstract Classes

Tags: c#, oop

I am learning OOP in C# however having trouble designing a mock application that simulates a University Card system which allows student and staff to access certain services/building.

[image]

I have a abstract class UniversityMember which contains information which is commons such as everyone has a firstname etc. I have interfaces which are more specific such as IStudent generates studentIds and set door/access level for each student using the enum AccessLevel class. However when I do

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Student Majid = new Student();

    Majid.FName = "foo";
    Majid.LName = "hello";
    Majid.SetStudentId();
    Majid.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2018, 09, 10);
    Majid.Type = MemberType.Student;

    Majid.setStudentLevel(AccessLevel.CharlesWilson,
                          AccessLevel.ComputerScienceBuilding,
                          AccessLevel.DavidWilson);

    PayTutionFees(Majid);
}

public static void PayTutionFees(IStudent student)
{
    //Design problem
    //student.ID  etc 
}
```

I use polymorphism because every student implements IStudent however I dont have access to the Student information as its located in the UniversityMember abstract class. I dont want to have the interfaces filled with repeated methods as their are common information shared between students and teaching staff. How could I get around this problem?

Comment: I don't see any classes than `Student` that implement `IStudent` and I suppose only students pay Tution fees. So maybe you could change parameter type for `Student`?

Comment: Okay, however what if I wanted a method to allow only GymMembers, student and staff both use the gym interface how would I do that?

Comment: Your parameter is IStudent and there is no ID property on IStudent. So `(Student)student.ID` would work. Or `studend as Student`. So prevent wrong casting you can check with `if(student.GetType() == typeof(Student))` or `student is Student`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the implementers of `IStudent`, `IWorkingStaff` etc. have some properties in common, you can describe those in a separate interface, say `IUniversityMember`:

```
public interface IUniversityMember
{
    String ID {get;}
    // etc.
}
```

And make your existing interfaces, which imply access to these common properties, extend `IUniversityMember`.

```
public interface IStudent : IUniversityMember {...}
public interface IWorkingStaff : IUniversityMember {...}
```

(Which means that both `IStudent` and `IWorkingStaff` now require their implementers to provide properties, listed in `IUniversityMember` interface in addition to their own.) Then you can make your abstract `UniversityMember` class implement this new `IUniversityMemeber`interface.

Since your concrete classes extend `UniversityMember` anyway, they will satisfy this wider interface automatically, having inherited all the properties, required by `IUniversityMember`, from their base abstract class.

In this way you'll be able to accept `IStudent` as parameter in your method and still have access to properties, which it has in common with other kinds of university members.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using interface as a parameter you can't use `student.ID` inside because you can't be sure that only `Student` class will implement given interface. You should rely only on interface members. In this case I suppose you just use wrong parameter type (as I've mentioned in my comment).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you did not separate an abstraction from the implementation. If you have more generic-like information, common for all members, then you should declare it in an interface, eg:

```
public interface IUniversityMember
{
    publis string Name {get;set;}
    publis string Id {get;set;}
}
```

and then inherit it in your `IStudent` interface:

```
public interface IStudent: IUniversityMember
{
    publis string StudentRelatedProperty {get;set;}
}
```

while your `UniversityMember` class should implement the `IUniversityMember`. An abstract class is an implementation detail, which should not be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

You try to acces IStudent.ID

```
public static void PayTutionFees(IStudent student)
{
    student.ID // at this point student is a IStudent so no ID prop available
}
```

You could start casting at this point

```
public static void PayTutionFees(IStudent student)
{
    //Design problem
    (Student)student.ID;
    var realStudent = student as Student;

    //to avoid wrong cast check for type before

    if(student.GetType() == typeof(Student))
    {//jippy student is a Student!}
}
```